# Grok Parsing Failure in logstash with Pattern That Includes Square Brackets

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have a log pattern where every log element is enclosed in square brackets. I can't control the original log. I just want the grok parsing to ignore the brackets and only interpret what's between them. Based on something close to the following line:

```
2019-04-04 13.23.57.057 [52] [77] [MEASURE] [XYZService]
```

, I want the pattern to see the 52 as a threadId. I have the following code:

```
if [message] =~ "MEASURE" {
    grok {
        match => { " message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logtime} [%{NUMBER:threadId}] %{GREEDYDATA:restofmessage}" }
    }
}
else {
    drop()
}
```

In this state, I get a grokparsefailure when logstash attempts to interpret the line. I am certain its only related to the bracketed portion, because when I remove that pattern, every works fine. I would be grateful for any ideas what I am doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nevermind. I got it to work by escaping the brackets like this: \ [ %{NUMBER:threadId}
\ ]